# Link to other page value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have the jqGrid below with two columns (user_id and user_name).  I want to pass a USER_NAME via GET parameter by page url, and jqGrid to move to that value page and show all records of that page. Is this possible since jqGrid only loads 25 records per page?

```javascript
$(document).ready(function() { 


   $("#list").jqGrid(
   {
    url:'index.cfc?method=getData', //CFC that will return the users
    datatype: 'json', //We specify that the datatype we will be using will be JSON
    mtype: 'POST',
    colNames:['User ID', 'User Name'], //Column Names
    colModel :[     
     {name:'user_id',index:'user_id', sorttype:"string", formatter: 'showlink', formatoptions:{baseLinkUrl:'#'}},
     {name:'user_name',index:'user_name', sorttype:"string"}
    ],
    pager: $('#pager'), //The div we have specified, tells jqGrid where to put the pager
    toppager: true,
    height: 'auto',
    width: 1270,
    rowNum:25, //Number of records we want to show per page
    rowList:[25,50,100], //Row List, to allow user to select how many rows they want to see per page
    sortorder: "asc", //Default sort order
    sortname: "user_id", //Default sort column
    loadComplete: function() {
     var myGrid = $("#list");
     var ids = myGrid.getDataIDs();
     for (var i = 0, idCount = ids.length; i < idCount; i++) {
      $("#"+ids[i]+" a",myGrid[0]).click(function(e) {
       var hash=e.currentTarget.hash;// string like "#?id=0"
       if (hash.substring(0,5) === '#?id=') {
        var id = hash.substring(5,hash.length);
        var text = this.textContent;
        alert("clicked the row with id='"+id+"'. Link contain '"+text+"'");
        location.href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/"+text;

       }
       e.preventDefault();

      });
     }  

     for(var i=0;i<ids.length;i++){ 
      var cl = ids[i]; 

       vdelete = "<a href='#' onclick=\"testfn('"+cl+"')\">Delete</a></ids>";  
       jQuery("#list").setRowData(ids[i],{act:vdelete}) 
     }     
    },
    caption: '', //Grid Name
    jsonReader: {
    root: "ROWS", //our data
    page: "PAGE", //current page
    total: "TOTAL", //total pages
    records:"RECORDS", //total records
    cell: "",
    id: "0"

    }
   })


   $("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',
   {
    edit:false,
    add:false,
    del:false, 
    search:true,
    refresh: true,
    searchtext:"Search",
    refreshtext: "Refresh",
    'cloneToTop':true
   }); 


  });
```

Comment: could you reduce your code to the "minimum needed to show what you want" - there is a lot here for someone to read through. Also add an "attempted solution" - where you want to "do something". For example right now you have an alert when a link is clicked - is that where you want to reload your grid? How do you intend to get to record #75 when you are showing 1-25? There will be no link to click... The clearest questions get the best answers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already got what i whant, on load complete e chef if the user_name vale is on that page, if not i go to next page and do the same...
But i cant do reloadGrid on loadComplete or gridComplete function!
Why i can't reload grid on this two functions?